# JQuery drag bug on chrome

Tags: jquery-ui

Jquery drag doesn't seem to behave correctly when chrome zoom is not at 100%. On this 
[jquery drag demo](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement), if you set the chrome zoom (ctrl + mousewheel up) to > 100%, on the first drag the box will stay within it's containment, but if you try to drag it out the second time it will actually break out of the containment area.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

i can't reproduce this with chrome 17.

additionaly, your question is about one year old, so it seems like this bug is fixed (either in chrome or in jquery). if you're still facing this problem, you should try to [create a ticket at bugs.jquery.com](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket?redirectedfrom=) giving exact information about the browser-version you're using to make them fix it instead of searching for a custom fix - that way, other developers get the benefit of a faultless jquery, too